# How to select and extract the rows with the same ID which has the minimum value in one column in jupyter?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I have a data frame that has some rows with the same ID which includes different starcounter values.
[image: the raw DataFrame]

I need to keep the rows with a minimum value and delete the extra rows to reach this table:
[image: Selected rows].

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is

```
df2 = df.sort_values('starcounter').drop_duplicates(['ID'], keep='first')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner to do this:

`df.loc[df.groupby('ID')['starcounter'].idxmin()]`